# I'll have this one!

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, word

- Through the web and morning view.
- Break from rise, it's perpendicular too.
- It can be rough or go on forever.
- Lets finish this rhyme by thinking about leather!

What is the subject?

Hint 1

> Use the hidden line to your advantage

Hint 2

> Forever - |1| For all future time; for always. |2| Continually. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/forever

Large hint 1

> **Through the web** - common phrase?

Large hint 2

> Think about gravity

Massive hint

> Portmanteau,imagery,description,example

The hint that ties everything together and gives away too much

> 4 lines, 4 individual hints. Hint 1 is tied to line 4. You can work out the rest

A bunch of loose ends to help you (Another hint of greater magnitude)

> The answer is staring you in the **face**. **Water** you going to do about it? It appears you are **going in circles**... why don't you **read the headline**? (4 ends, 4 parts)

Comment: This is a riddle about something. The lines **aren't** coherent! There is no letters magic

Comment: What do you mean by "the lines aren't coherent"?

Comment: The lines aren't connected to each other. They are independent

Comment: Guess the bounty isn't going to go... This one has been a real melon-scratcher, even with the plethora of clues provided!

Comment: Im going to hold onto this bounty till the very last minute for a fresh 23h. If there is still no acceptable answer then I may award it to the best attempt. I would fully support another bounty but everyone is close to the answer and I expect it to be solved soon

Comment: @Adam I think I know it, but can't seem to find anywhere to answer

Comment: @CodeBoyCode this is because this question is protected. You need at least 10 reputation from this site and association bonus does not count! https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is

> Surface

*Through the web and morning view*

> Through the web = surf + morning view = face (you look in a mirror in the morning to get ready for work etc.)

*Break from rise, it's perpendicular too*

> Waves can break and rise from the surface of the ocean, perpendicular to the surface

*It can be rough or go on forever*

> A surface can be rough (like the surface of the sea), or so smooth it appears to go on forever (i.e. to the horizon in the case of the sea)

*Let's finish this rhyme by thinking about leather*

> Leather is an example of a surface

Comment: Well I wish I still had the bounty to give. No the answer is not this however your answer practically echoes the intended one! You've got the common phrase hint correct. You've got a 2nd line interpretation which is almost spot on (applied to different idea). Carefully reconsider the 3rd line. The last line doesn't need to rhyme with anything but the line before it

Comment: @Adam is the updated guess any closer?

Comment: OK, as the bounty-receiver, I am now giving you a +1 as a kind of compensation and in deep respect! Well done!

Comment: @Dmihawk the answer is **surface** well done. Although line 3 was referring to surfaces in general and leather is an example of a surface but same thing

Comment: @Dmihawk once you tidy up your answer ill accept it

Comment: Cleaned up the answer, still unsure on the title though, would you mind explaining it?

Comment: @Dmihawk Sure, the title "I'll have this one" refers to the selection of surfaces...the twist of this riddle is that the person asking the riddle was thinking about getting a leather surface (for a couch etc)

Comment: Could anyone please explain Hint1 and large hint 2 in connection with the accepted answer? Also how does the last hint 'going in circles' is related? Genuinely curious!

Comment: @mocarsha2019 yea, the accepted answer kinda misses out on that stuff however it was close enough. The line 2 and 3 answer is not exactly the intended one and that may cause some confusion with the large amount of details getting thrown around. You "break the surface" when rising for air in a body of water, this ties into gravity since **the surface of water is always perpendicular to gravity** and you could also interpret this as **since water is perpendicular to gravity, the buoyancy force acts perpendicular to the surface**. Going in circles refers to surfaces that wrap around. Hint 1>title

Answer (score 3):

Through the web and morning view.

> The letter W

Break from rise, it's perpendicular too.

> The letter I

It can be rough or go on forever.

> The letter C

Lets finish this rhyme by thinking about leather!

> The letter K which *L-eat-her*

Comment: the last two are complete leaps, you don't explain them at all. Why did they occur to you, why are they right?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that

> each line of the riddle yields one letter of a word.

*Through the web and morning view.*

> "the web" might suggest **W** as in WWW?

*Break from rise, it's perpendicular too.*

> Maybe the letter **I**, which is made up of a "perpendicular" line, and "rise" sounds like "eyes"/"I"s.

*It can be rough or go on forever.*

> Rough **C**s or seas, which can look like they go on forever.

*Lets finish this rhyme by thinking about leather!*

> Dunno about this, but given the other letters it seems like ...

the final answer should be

> WICK.

Comment: Ask yourself why would I be thinking about leather?

Comment: @Adam Could there be a connection between the KKK and leather, perhaps?

Comment: No. My point was that you won't be able to accommodate this without reconsidering your whole answer. Can you read my comment under my question to update yourself

Answer (score 2):

The subject is

> **TIME**

- Through the web and morning view.

  > You could estimate the time at your place when you have a morning view or by simply looking it up the web(internet).
- Break from rise, it's perpendicular too.

  > The approx time of sunrise is around 6 in the morning. Which is when the hour and minute hand of the clock form one straight line, in other words, are perpendicular to the general horizontal plane.
- It can be rough or go on forever.

  > Times can be rough in life in different situations of struggles and hardships. And regardless of the world, time goes on forever(Time and tide wait for none after all).
- Lets finish this rhyme by thinking about leather!

  > What tells you the time after all? It's a simple device called a watch. Which most commonly is a dial with **leather** straps. So, if you think of time, have it always by you strapped in leather onto your wrist.

Comment: Great answer! The reasoning of line 2 is a bit out-there and this isn't the intended answer but it is a really good fit to this riddle. I would've accepted this as an alternate answer if not for one small thing about the riddle that disproves this answer

Comment: would it be too obvious if i could ask what that small thing about the riddle is that disproves my answer? Maybe i could get back on the right track using it.

Comment: Sure, see hint 1

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the subject is

> Heather

Through the web and morning view.

> Heather is thick and bushy, and sort of web-like.

Break from rise, it’s perpendicular too.

> Heather rises from its ashes- after burning, new plants arise.

It can be rough or go on forever.

> Heather is rough and stretches over large tracts of moorland easily.

Lets finish this rhyme by thinking about leather!

> *Heather*, of course, rhymes with *leather*.

Comment: @Adam is my answer right?

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier. It isn't

Comment: @Adam is it this then?

Comment: No but there is one final hint that has been added good luck!

Answer (score 2):

With all those hints, large and small, I believe the answer is:

> FEATHER

Through the web and morning view.

> Through-the sounds like feather

Break from rise, it's perpendicular too.

> rise: stalk of feather, it breaks into a lot of "hairs". Perpendicular: perhaps referring to the angle between hairs and stalk?

It can be rough or go on forever.

> rough? forever: there are some large feathers that may go on and on if you touch it.

Lets finish this rhyme by thinking about leather!

> 1) they are both materials. 2) they rhyme!

---

HINTS

Hint 1

```
Use the hidden line to your advantage
```

> 

Hint 2

```
Forever - |1| For all future time; for always. |2| Continually. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/forever
```

> Let me know that forever doesn't necessarily mean never-stopping

Large hint 1

```
Through the web - common phrase?
```

> Let me think of the sound of "through the"

Large hint 2

```
Think about gravity
```

> ?? Light as a feather?

Massive hint

```
Portmanteau,imagery,description,example
```

> refers to each of the four lines: great hint!

Comment: You are very close. There is something **special** about the first four hints. You've understood hint 2 and the massive hint correctly. Your line 1 interpretation is too cryptic and doesn't include the whole line. Line 3 makes more sense when you have the answer. Your line 4 interpretation includes something **very important**

Comment: @Adam is RandAlThor's answer of great use to me? thanks!

Comment: No, your answer is more on track. Your overall answer is not the intended one but your reasoning is on track to get you the right answer

Comment: @Adam is the answer rot13(jrngure)?

Comment: How does "through the" sound like <your answer>??

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking off of Rand al'Thor's answer, I think I can add the last line's clue

Through the web and morning view.

> The letter *W*

Break from rise, it's perpendicular too.

> The letter *I*

It can be rough or go on forever.

> The letter *C*

As Rand al'Thor pointed out, it looks like the last line should signify a

> *K*. Since it's obvious, the letter isn't actually found here, and the leather references John Wick and his brown leather jacket.

As an aside, did I correctly form the possessive of "Rand al'Thor" back at the beginning?

Comment: This riddle doesn't require any knowledge of any franchise to be solved. Ask yourself why would I be thinking about leather (without any reference to external works). My point is that you won't be able to accommodate this without reconsidering your whole answer!

Comment: Rot13(Jura V guvax bs yrngure, V guvax bs pbjf, snezf, naq '90f pybguvat.) The "snez" would fit, except I dunno what to do with the perpindicular part of the poem. @Adam

Comment: What I will say is that the lines of the riddle aren't coherent! You are missing something vital with line 4 and something else

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's

> A Current

Through the web and morning view.

> The web could mean the internet and one can see currents on their computer. People with beach houses may see currents when they look into the ocean.

Break from rise, it's perpendicular too.

> When waves break near the shoreline, a rip current forms **perpendicular** to the shoreline.

It can be rough or go on forever.

> Rip currents are very rough and ocean currents move water forever.

Lets finish this rhyme by thinking about leather!

> I haven't figured out how this relates to currents.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be

> LIGHT?

*Through the web and morning view.*

> You might see sunlight through a spider's web in a morning view (or dew).

*Break from rise, it's perpendicular too.*

> Daybreak from sunrise, bringing light back to the world. Light is formed of [electromagnetic waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) which oscillate perpendicularly.

*It can be rough or go on forever.*

> I don't know about rough, but a ray of light can in theory go on forever.

*Lets finish this rhyme by thinking about leather!*

> A *light* leather jacket? [Light leather?](https://www.wowhead.com/item=2318/light-leather) (I Googled that last one.)

Comment: Hah, getting use out of my physics knowledge! It would be strange to say that light is rough and trying to relate it to leather in this way but this is a creative approach! You are getting closer. Use hint 1 and try to incorporate the last line as it is very important

Comment: Oh and my comments about lines weren't a cryptic hint towards rot13(yvtug (vagresrerapr naq cubgbaf))

Answer (score 1):

Through the web and morning view

> Perhaps the latitudinal/longitudinal lines on a globe?

Break from rise, it's perpendicular too

> The equator, perhaps?

It can be rough or go on forever

> Spinning a globe manually vs the regular rotation of the earth?

Let's finish this rhyme by thinking about leather

> Globes are often made of leather

Comment: Nice try, not the answer. If you go along the same line of reasoning however you may end up with the answer

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Leather Webbing

Through the web and morning view.

> **Web** - morn-**ing**-Portmanteau

Break from rise, it's perpendicular too.

> perpendicular as in used to climb mountains, etc

It can be rough or go on forever.

> like a rope goes on forever

Lets finish this rhyme by thinking about leather!

> Webbing made of leather

Comment: Try to include the whole riddle in your answer. Use hints to help

Comment: new edit - That ignores "Through the" and "morn... view"

Answer (score 1):

With all those hints, large and small, I believe the answer is:

> WEATHER (great thanks to @KradCigol in comments of my prev answer)

Through the web and morning view.

> web: you can search the web for the weather; 
>  morning view: you can see the weather by looking up the sky in the morning

Break from rise, it's perpendicular too.

> break from rise: referring to the sun rising from the east? 
> perpendicular: to the horizon, or another case: rain usually falls vertically? (Not so true)

It can be rough or go on forever.

> rough: sometimes the weather is bad, i.e. rough
>  forever: a long period of rain seems to be going on forever, or weather never stops, does it?

Lets finish this rhyme by thinking about leather!

> leather rhymes with leather (PS: what is the important bit?)

---

HINTS

Hint 1

```
Use the hidden line to your advantage
```

> refers to line 4, 'tis a nice one:) "hidden line" --> hide the 'l' from "leather", "eather" remains --> sounds like "weather"

Hint 2

```
Forever - |1| For all future time; for always. |2| Continually. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/forever
```

> Refers to line 3, lets me know that forever doesn't necessarily mean never-stopping

Large hint 1

```
Through the web - common phrase?
```

> Refers to line 1, but why?

Large hint 2

```
Think about gravity
```

> Refers to line 2, the rain bit

Massive hint

```
Portmanteau,imagery,description,example
```

> refers to each of the four lines: great hint!

Comment: @Dragonchild No problem, its fine ;) happy puzzling :)

Comment: Its not weather, already told @KradCigol it wasn't. Since it is so close to the bounty end I will ask you this final question... **is there anything parallel to the horizon that can solve the whole riddle?**

Answer (score 0):

The subject is

> **TIME**

- Through the web and morning view.

  > We guess the Time by the shadow of some object caused by the sun. Also, can look the internet or web of watches(At this era there are more watches than ever before).
- Break from the rise, it's perpendicular too.

  > As soon as the rise of sun ends or breaks, the sun makes 90 degrees angle with the horizon (The hidden line).
- It can be rough or go on forever.

  > Sometimes you are happy sometimes sad. Sometimes very difficult to pass the time. everyone gets a rough situation. The quote suits both the situation of happiness and sadness. "This time will pass". This quote will be forever true.
- Let's finish this rhyme by thinking about leather!

  > Think about leather or a chain or a rubber strap. The watch suits all.

Comment: The horizon isn't a hidden line. Anyway the advice is to see hint 1 again. The point was that hint 1 **disproves** this subject

Answer (score 0):

is it

> lathe machine

Through the web and morning view.

> 

Break from rise, it's perpendicular too.

> it's working involves perpendicular stuff

It can be rough or go on forever.

> it does work continually

Lets finish this rhyme by thinking about leather!

> lathe and leather might rhyme

Hint 1
    Use the hidden line to your advantage

> in engineering drawing *hidden lines* are used and help in lathe machines

Hint 2
    Forever - |1| For all future time; for always.

> spins, spins, spins

Large hint 1
    Through the web - common phrase?

> 

Large hint 2
    Think about gravity

> uses it

Massive hint

```
Portmanteau,imagery,description,example
```

> used description/example

PS:I know I wrote another answer (I'm new so please let me know if it's not allowed)

Comment: You are allowed multiple answers as long as they are not correlated (I think im kinda new also). This isn't the intended answer

Answer (score 0):

With all those hints, large and small, I believe the answer is:

> MATTER

Through the web and morning view.

> the Web and Light (morning view) are not matters?

Break from rise, it's perpendicular too.

> perhaps referring to this? ;)
> [image]

It can be rough or go on forever.

> rough: there are some rough matter 
> forever: matters/ problems keep unsolved and go on forever if you  don't solve them

Lets finish this rhyme by thinking about leather!

> 1) leather is an example of matter 2) they rhyme!

---

HINTS

Hint 1

```
Use the hidden line to your advantage
```

> perhaps this can be an example? https://www.britannica.com/topic/hidden-line

Hint 2

```
Forever - |1| For all future time; for always. |2| Continually. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/forever
```

> Let me know that forever doesn't necessarily mean never-stopping

Large hint 1

```
Through the web - common phrase?
```

> 

Large hint 2

```
Think about gravity
```

> matter is attracted by gravity

Massive hint

```
Portmanteau,imagery,description,example
```

> refers to each of the four lines: great hint!

Comment: Nope. There is something **special** about the first four hints. Your line 4 interpretation **doesn't** include something important anymore. Quoting myself "There is no letters magic". Is there anything strange in the riddle and does it have anything to do with large hint 2?

Answer (score 0):

is it

> Tether

Through the web and morning view.

> tethering hotspot for web

Break from rise, it's perpendicular too.

> tethering animals doesn't allow them to rise and the angle between the rope and pole is 90 degrees

It can be rough or go on forever.

> rough for the animals and goes on forever

Lets finish this rhyme by thinking about leather!

> leather is what we get from the animals in the end

Large hint 1 Through the web - common phrase?

> tethering hitspot

Large hint 2 Think about gravity

> that's what keeps things in place

Comment: You have to incorporate everything into your answer. The answer to this riddle is elegant and fits everything. You cannot be confident with your answer if it doesn't fit everything or there is no attempt to fit everything. Anyway, this is not the answer, try again. Start with the massive hint first then work towards an answer

Answer (score 0):

is it

> WIND

Through the web and morning view.

> it passes *through* webs and morning view

Break from rise, it's perpendicular too.

> breaks strings, objects rise; wind is perpendicular

It can be rough or go on forever.

> obviously wind can

Lets finish this rhyme by thinking about leather!

> wearing leather jacket allows us to fight the wind

Hint 1
    Use the hidden line to your advantage

> decide your direction/angle of walking according to the **invisible** direction of the wind

Hint 2
    Forever - |1| For all future time; for always.

> from one place to the next place goes on and on

Large hint 1

Through the web-common phrase?

> in the wind phrase, romour on the web, romour in the wind

Large hint 2
    Think about gravity

> uses it

Massive hint

```
Portmanteau,imagery,description,example
```

> as already pointed out, one for each line

Comment: Would be a perfect answer but the wording of the riddle doesn't allow it

Comment: @Adam what do you mean by 'wording of the riddle'?

Comment: I was trying to say that it is too far-fetched given the nature of the riddle. Would of been perfect if the riddle was phrased and structured differently. Its difficult telling you that it is not close to the answer given how many different ideas you have contributed

Answer (score 0):

With all those hints, large and small, I believe the **best** answer is:

> WATER

Through the web and morning view.

> web: water can go **through** a web; 
>  morning view: morning dew on leaves

Break from rise, it's perpendicular too.

> imagery: a water fountain: It shoots out perpendicularly, and breaks into different angles when falling back down, from rising

It can be rough or go on forever.

> rough: [rough water](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rough%20water)
>  forever: seas and oceans were, according to ancient thoughts, boundless and go on *forever*

Lets finish this rhyme by thinking about leather!

> leather rhymes with water, and water is a *material*?

---

HINTS

Hint 1

```
Use the hidden line to your advantage
```

> refers to line 4, ?

Hint 2

```
Forever - |1| For all future time; for always. |2| Continually. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/forever
```

> Refers to line 3, lets me know that forever doesn't necessarily mean never-stopping

Large hint 1

```
Through the web - common phrase?
```

> Refers to line 1, water goes through a web

Large hint 2

```
Think about gravity
```

> Refers to line 2, for cases both artificial (fountains) and natural (e.g. waterfall, or precipitations like rain, snow, hail, etc.)

Massive hint

```
Portmanteau,imagery,description,example
```

> refers to each of the four lines: great hint!

Loose bits

```
The answer is staring you in the **face**. **Water** you going to do about it? It appears you are **going in circles**... why don't you **read the headline**? (4 ends, 4 parts)
```

> ??

Comment: Very far off of the answer now, remember to use the hints to your advantage and fully incorporate them. However, you **correctly interpreted part of line 4** again